# lock or unlock cell using a input in a specified cell in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**Updated!**

[image]I have a sheet in which all of the cells are locked and hidden without 2 cells. E.g. `A1` and `A20`

Now I want that if I input "Belly" in cell `A20` then the cell `A1` will be Unlocked. Again if I remove text "Belly" from cell `A20` then cell `A1` will be locked.

I have written this code :

```
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim inputCell As Range
Dim machine As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set targetCell = Range("A1")
Set inputCell = Range("A20")
Set machine = "Belly"

If inputCell.Value = "Belly" Then
    ws.Unprotect Password:="mehedi"
    targetCell.Locked = False
    ws.Protect Password:="mehedi"
Else
    ws.Unprotect Password:="mehedi"
    targetCell.Locked = True
    ws.Protect Password:="mehedi"

End Sub
```

But it is not working and giving error. Please help out.

Comment: "But it is not working and giving error", what error?

Comment: I have uploaded the screen shot of my error in the question. please see it.

Comment: Hey @Mehedi,,, plz [edit] your post & upload the Error message screen shot,,, also check the Protection/Un-protection sequence ,, initially the whole Sheet except A1 & A20 must be protected,,, and U r working in reverse order!!

Comment: @Mehedi,, either use MACHINE variable, or use the value Belly,, U r trying to use both,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code, you have declare "machine" as string. Yet, when assigning a value to it, you are using `Set`. It should be:

```
machine="Belly"
```

See [Set statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Comment: It works without error! Thanks bro @Reddy Lutonadio. Yes, it's because of the set statement. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If and only if this answer is satisfactory and has solved your issue, you can mark it as answered.

Comment: Okay bro. Thanks again!

Comment: brother, Will you check it out? https://superuser.com/q/1579816/1207783