# Slowing down my sheet and erases all other contents after the if function in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a sheet that is protected and locked all the cells without the fruit selected cell as if `B2`. I have written a code like this :
If I enter "Mango" in cell `B2` then the sheet will be unprotected and unlock the cell `J2` and again protect the worksheet. Then when I enter a numeric value in the cell `J2` like "15", it will insert a row in row 15. Then merge `A15:C15`. It runs well.
But the problem is that when it inserts a row then all the other contents below that row are vanished. Moreover in this code my sheet is lacking. What can I do.
Please help.
The code is given for your reference :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim inputCell As Integer
Dim copyRange As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim validateCell As String
Dim fruitType As String

inputCell = Range("J2").Value
copyRange = "A" & inputCell
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
validateCell = Range("B2").Value
fruitType = "Mango"

If validateCell = fruitType Then
   ws.Unprotect Password:="mehedi"
   Range("J2").Locked = False
   ws.Protect Password:="mehedi"
End If

If Range("J2").Value >= 5 Then
   ws.Unprotect Password:="mehedi"
   Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Insert
   Range(copyRange & ":C" & inputCell).Merge
   Range(copyRange & ":C" & inputCell).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
   Range("D" & inputCell & ":F" & inputCell).Merge
   Range("D" & inputCell & ":F" & inputCell).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
End If
End Sub
```

**Update for @FlexYourData**

[image]

Comment: Hey @Mehedi,,, you need to follow proper sequence,, since you have started with Unprotect,,, but before that the sheet has to protect. And U have missed setting cell B2 , unprotect. since you are trying to Copy along with Old data so U have to work with Last Row method also.

Comment: Which sequence I didn't follow?I first of all I protected my sheet without cell B2. Then I run the code so that when I enter the correct information in cell b2 then the cell J2 will be unlock. which sequence I didn't follow can you explain @RajeshS ?

Comment: Check If Validatecell,,,, after the first Unprotect comes,,, before that no where sheet got ptotection.

Answer (score 2):

It's important when using `Worksheet_Change` to make reference to the `Target` range.

I set up some dummy data. `J2` was blank. I typed Mango into `B2` and stepped into the Sub routine. Note that when we start, inputCell is zero (because `J2` is blank).

[image]

So, `copyRange` will be "A0", which is not a valid address. This is not the cause of your problem here, but it could cause problems elsewhere.

We can use `Target` to check which cell has been edited. So for your situation, you would use something like this:

```
If Target.AddressLocal = "$J$2" Then
    'do something when J2 was changed
    
ElseIf Target.AddressLocal = "$B$2" Then
    'do something when B2 was changed
    
Else
    'do something else, or nothing

End If
```

Every time your current code calls `.EntireRow.Insert`, it's causing the `Worksheet_Change` event to be called again, which is causing another row to be inserted, which is causing the event to be called again, which is causing another row, and so on. In fact, I suspect your code will continue inserting rows like this, causing your data below to seem as if it has vanished. This is also likely causing slowness.

So, you should always refer to `Target` so that the macro only takes action when you have changed specific cells (and not when you are inserting the row).

One other item you might want to consider is putting putting your password as a constant in this sheet or global constant in another module. If you then don't want users to see that password, you will need to lock the VBA project, as described [here](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/lock-excel-vba-project-with-password.html). This will help you a little I think as you will only have to type it once in the VBA project, so there are fewer opportunities for typos.

See if this works for you by pasting it in the code behind the worksheet. `Option Explicit` is usually a good idea as it forces the system to not accept variables unless they are `Dim`'d

```
Option Explicit

Const pwd As String = "mehedi"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim inputCell As Integer
Dim copyRange As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim validateCell As String
Dim fruitType As String

'this is just giving a short name for the current sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'set this at the top
fruitType = "Mango"

If Target.AddressLocal = "$J$2" Then
    'do something when J2 was changed
    inputCell = Target

    'only take action if the condition is met
    If inputCell >= 5 Then
        copyRange = "A" & inputCell
        
        ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
        
        ws.Range(copyRange).EntireRow.Insert 'causes this event to fire again, so be careful~
        
        ws.Range(copyRange & ":C" & inputCell).Merge
        ws.Range(copyRange & ":C" & inputCell).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
        
        ws.Range("D" & inputCell & ":F" & inputCell).Merge
        ws.Range("D" & inputCell & ":F" & inputCell).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
        
        'perhaps you need this here as well?
        ws.Protect Password:=pwd
    End If
    
ElseIf Target.AddressLocal = "$B$2" And Target.Value = fruitType Then
    'only take action if the right fruit was entered into the right cell
    
        ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd
        ws.Range("J2").Locked = False
        ws.Protect Password:=pwd


End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:

The code as listed above works just fine in this series of steps:

1. all cells except B2 are locked
2. enter "Mango" in B2
3. Sheet is unprotected, J2 is unlocked, Sheet is protected
4. enter 15 in J2
5. row is inserted above current row 15, A15:C15 are merged and given a border, D15:F15 are merged and given a border

The only thing I can think at this time is there is some detail about your problem which you haven't stated. In that case, you will need to debug this issue.

Comment: bro there is two problem in your code. First of all you have a small misunderstanding in the concept. My code was like that first of all my sheet will be totally locked and protected without cell B2. When I enter "Mango" in that cell (B2) then the cell J2 will be unlocked. Again the sheet will be protected. Then I will put a numeric value in cell J2. That values row will be inserted and the rest of the design will be executed and again protect the sheet. The other problem is that your code is giving an error. I am uploading the screen shot of the error in my question section. Pls look it out.

Comment: I understood the concept. What is the error?

Comment: Run time error. Type mismatch

Comment: Try removing `.Value` so it just says `Target = fruitType` instead.

Comment: nope. It didn't work.

Comment: See my edit. The code works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112186/discussion-between-mehedi-and-flexyourdata).